# Overriding method to swipe away wear app

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, wear-os

I am making an app that requires a background service on Android Wear. I was able to get it to run in the background. Going to a different app or clicking the home button doesn't stop the service, but swiping right on the MainActivity stops the app and the activity. This is the obvious way to get back to the watch face so I don't want to disable the swipe. Is there a way to override this action?

Edit: Here is my code. I added `START_STICKY` as suggested but have not seen a difference.

```
public class MusicService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener,
MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener, MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener, MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener,
AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener {

private MediaPlayer player;
private List<Song> songs;
private int songIndex;
private final IBinder musicBind = new MusicBinder();
private AudioManager audioManager;

public void onCreate() {
    // Create the service
    super.onCreate();
    songIndex = 0;
    player = new MediaPlayer();

    initMusicPlayer();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    String mediaFile = "";
    try {
        //An audio file is passed to the service through putExtra();
        mediaFile = songs.get(songIndex).uri;
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        stopSelf();
    }

    //Request audio focus
    if (requestAudioFocus() == false) {
        //Could not gain focus
        stopSelf();
    }

    if (mediaFile != null && mediaFile != "")
        initMusicPlayer();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, START_STICKY);
}

public void initMusicPlayer() {
    // Set player properties
    player.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
    player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    player.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    player.setOnErrorListener(this);
}
public void setSong(int songIndex) {
    this.songIndex = songIndex;
}

public void setList(List<Song> songs) {
    this.songs = songs;
}

public class MusicBinder extends Binder {
    MusicService getService() {
        return MusicService.this;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i, int i1) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusState) {
    switch (focusState) {
        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN:
            // resume playback
            if (player == null) initMusicPlayer();
            else if (!player.isPlaying()) player.start();
            player.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
            break;
        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS:
            // Lost focus for an unbounded amount of time: stop playback and release media player
            if (player.isPlaying()) player.stop();
            player.release();
            player = null;
            break;
        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT:
            // Lost focus for a short time, but we have to stop
            // playback. We don't release the media player because playback
            // is likely to resume
            if (player.isPlaying()) player.pause();
            break;
        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK:
            // Lost focus for a short time, but it's ok to keep playing
            // at an attenuated level
            if (player.isPlaying()) player.setVolume(0.1f, 0.1f);
            break;
    }
}

private boolean requestAudioFocus() {
    audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int result = audioManager.requestAudioFocus(this, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
    if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
        //Focus gained
        return true;
    }
    //Could not gain focus
    return false;
}

private boolean removeAudioFocus() {
    return AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED ==
            audioManager.abandonAudioFocus(this);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return musicBind;
}

@Override
public  boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    player.stop();
    player.release();
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {

}



@Override
public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i, int i1) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    mediaPlayer.start();
}

public void playSong() {
    player.reset();
    Song playSong = songs.get(songIndex);
    Uri trackUri = Uri.parse(playSong.uri);

    try {
        player.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), trackUri);
        player.prepareAsync();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("Music Service", "Error setting data source", ex);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: maybe you could make your service return START_STICKY in its onStartCommand(), so that the OS starts the service back.

Comment: I tried it with START_STICKY but haven't seen a difference. Maybe there is something in my code I am missing. I am also using `unbindService(musicConnection);` `onDestroy` in the main activity, but removing this just throws and error "mediaplayer went away with unhandled events"

Comment: If you are using intent to send data, then try using `START_REDELIVER_INTENT`

Comment: I am not sending any data over the intent. All data is stored in private variables.

Comment: there is this comment in your code : `//An audio file is passed to the service through putExtra();`. The point is, once the service is killed, only OS or a some broadcast listener can start it back. If you want the OS to start it back, the only thing you can do is return the correct value in your `onStartCommand()`.
PS : I hope you are doing this in a started service. and not in a bound service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically I had to add a function to request audio focus before playing music. For anyone interested, I was following this tutorial:
https://www.sitepoint.com/a-step-by-step-guide-to-building-an-android-audio-player-app/
Then in the `onDestroy` function of the service, leave out the line `removeAudioFocus` to let the music continue.

Edit: a better way seems to be follow the tutorial, but in the onDestroy method of the main activity, only unbind the service. My previous method would work, but would crash on some devices.